# TypeError in Getting Started with Rails tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was just trying out Ruby on Rails with the [Getting Started with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) tutorial. I followed all the steps but i keep getting the error **TypeError in PostsController#create**.

This happens when i'm at step 5.6 Saving data in the controller.

My PostsController.rb looks like this:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    @post.save
    redirect_to @post
  end

  private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
  end
end
```

and i'm at localhost:3000/posts/new. I'm requesting a POST and it fails with the following:

> can't convert Symbol into String

```
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:15:in `post_params'
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:7:in `create'
```

> This error occurred while loading the following files: post

You can find all my code on [my GitHub repo](https://github.com/kovacshuni/getting-started-with-rails).

Please help :(

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! For a faster response, it's best to post all relevant sections of code in your post.

Comment: Awh, there is a separate tutorial especially for Rails 3.2.xx. Following those steps solves it.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/getting_started.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using rails version 3.2.xx, on rails version 3.2.xx not include strong_parameters gem

> Note that def post_params is private. This new approach prevents an
>   attacker from setting the model's attributes by manipulating the hash
>   passed to the model. For more information, refer to this blog post
>   about [Strong Parameters.](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/3/21/strong-parameters/)

---

1. Add `gem "strong_parameters"` to your Gemfile, then run `bundle install`
2. include `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection` on your model or create `config/initializers/strong_parameters.rb` and put this :

   > `ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include,
   >   ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection))`
3. `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false` in `config/application.rb`

https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters